# smack UserSearchManager with ejabberd

Tags: java, android, ejabberd, smack, asmack

i'm trying to build a chat on android with ejabberd (15.11) and smack (4.1.5).

Before sending a subscribe Stanza i would like to check if this user exists on my server by checking if the jid is already in use:

```
    UserSearchManager userSearchManager = new UserSearchManager(connection);
    Form searchForm = userSearchManager.getSearchForm("vjud." + connection.getServiceName());       
    Form answerForm = searchForm.createAnswerForm();
    answerForm.setAnswer("user", userName + "@" + connection.getServiceName());
    ReportedData data = userSearchManager.getSearchResults(answerForm, "vjud." + connection.getServiceName());
```

I get multiple columns from my server, but no rows - means no data.
Doesn't matter if I just take the userName or Jid.

I do nothing else than register a user with a password, so firstname or something like this is not set.

Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong or where the best place is to look up the set Answer parameters? I searched a lot but couldn't find any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jabber User directory is based on Vcard. Users that do not have a Vcard will not be searchable through User directory. It means that indeed, registering a user is not enough to make it appear in Jabber Search directory.

Comment: is there a way to automatically add the first part of the jid (everything before the @) to the Vcard?